# Crontab run PHP script syslog issue

Tags: php, cron, syslog

I develop a PHP file which contains many `syslog(LOG_INFO, myINFO)` commands,
and I run that PHP file by browser, the`syslog` will works fine.
Unfortunately, I use `crontab` run that PHP file,
all the `syslog` doesn't work. It doesn't log anything.
Does anybody knows what the problem is?
Thanks!

ps. my crontab command is `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myphp.php  >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: What user are you running this as? Does it work when you call the file from the command line?

Comment: @Pekka웃 thank you very much, I change that running that php by root, it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. But do consider running it as a more secure user than root. A malicious PHP script running as root could destroy your entire system.